# Android AudioRecord read(...) method - will it return same values if invoked twice in a short period of time?

Tags: android, audiorecord

I'm working with Android audio, using AudioRecord to capture audio in real time. I'm using AudioRecord's read(...) method to obtain audio samples. Sample rate is 48000Hz and in read(...) method i want to get 1/4 of that which is 12000 samples. What will hapen if i call read method let's say 10 times per second ? Will it return overlapping values ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "No". You won't read the same data twice out of the `AudioRecord`. `read()` blocks until at least one "chunk" of new audio becomes available. `read()s` are not timing-sensitive, except in the sense that if you wait *too long*, parts of the `AudioRecord's` internal buffer will get lost/overwritten (since it is of finite size).

Source: Personal experience and many hours of testing on multiple devices, both real and emulated.